# Получить данные sql проверив несколько таблиц

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть уникальный идентификатор в таблице `link` , имея его нужно получить данные из таблицы `product`, получается нужно проверить таблица `table_10` и `table_11` на совпадение (например `table_11.id = link.id_version`) и уже от туда опять же сравнивая `table_11.id_product = product.id` попасть в `product` и получить нужную информацию. Пишу запрос

```
SELECT product.name
    , product.category_id
    , product.description 
FROM product, table_11, link 
WHERE link.id_version = table_11.id 
      AND table_11.id_product = product.id
```

и получаю данные из нужной таблицы, но при этом пройдя только через `table_11`, если я пытаюсь пройти через обе таблицы то не получаю вообще ничего, пишу условия через `or`, не знаю как проверить обе таблицы правильно что бы получить нужны результат

Comment: используйте два  запроса а результаты объедините через `UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соберите две однотипные таблицы в одну, в самом запросе (хотя если таблицы одинаковы по структуре, то возможно их и в БД стоило бы сделать в виде одной таблицы).

```
SELECT product.name, product.category_id, product.description 
  FROM product,
       ( select id, id_product from table_10
        union all
         select id, id_product from table_11
       ) as A,
       link 
 WHERE link.id_version = A.id 
   AND A.id_product = product.id
```

P.S. Вы не указали используемую СУБД. В некоторых слово `as` необходимо, а в некоторых на оборот, не допустимо и имя подзапроса пишется сразу за закрывающейся скобкой.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 СУБД , Ваш ответ подходит, но у меня возник еще вопрос , я его не указал заранее, в table_10 и table_11 есть поле price, как можно его еще вывести?

Comment: Извините за глупы вопрос, уже решил проблему )